# Why is my linked list deleting after a function call?

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-management, linked-list

In the code below I attempt to create a linked list of strings. I then use the linked list to store output generated by a function (named myFunction) which calls itself recursively. When testing/debugging the code, I noticed that if I print the contents of the linked list after executing the function (which should add items to the linked list) nothing prints out. However, if I attempt to print the linked list after adding items from inside the function it works fine.

It appears that the entire linked list is deleted after the call to myFunction. On the other hand, I'm using dynamic memory allocation when I add elements to the linked list so I don't see the issue.

Please help!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class node{
    public:
    node *next;
    T data;
    node(){next=0;};
    void print();
};

template <class T>
void node<T>::print(){
    std::cout << data;
}


template <class T>
class List{
public:
    node<T> *head;
    List(){head=0;};
    void add(T data);
    void print();
    int len();
};

template <class T>
int List<T>::len(){
    int i=0;
    node<T> *current=head;

    while(current!= 0){
        i++;
        current=current->next;
    }
    return i;
};

template <class T>
void List<T>::add(T myData){
    node<T> *current=head;
    if(head==0){
        head= new node<T>;
        head->data=myData;
    }
    else{

        while(current->next!=0){
            current=current->next;
        }

        current->next = new node<T>; 
        current->next->data=myData;
    }
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::print(void){
    node<T> *current=head;
    if(head==0){
        return;
    }
    else{
        do{
            std::cout << current->data << " ";   
            current=current->next;
        }while(current!=0);
    }
}

void myFunction(List<std::string> myList, int n, std::string starter, int leftParens, int rightParens){
    int remainingLength = leftParens+rightParens;
    if(remainingLength==0){
        myList.add(starter);
        std::cout <<myList.len() << std::endl;

    } 
    if(leftParens >0){
        myFunction(myList, n, starter+"(", leftParens-1, rightParens);
    }
    if(leftParens==0 and rightParens >0){
        myFunction(myList, n, starter+")", leftParens, rightParens-1);
    }

}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   List<std::string> myList;

   myFunction(myList, 5, "", 5, 5);
   std::cout <<myList.len();

}
```

Comment: You wanted to pass your list by reference ? Like :

`void myFunction(List<std::string> & myList, int n, std::string starter, int leftParens, int rightParens)`


myFunction just took a copy of the list, worked on it and returned without making any change to `myList` in main()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing `myList` to `myFunction` by value. Any changes made to `myList` in the function are changes to the copy, not the original `myList` in `main`.

Change `myFunction` so that it accepts its argument by reference. Then, any changes made to it in `myFunction` will also be visible in `main`.

```
void myFunction(List<std::string>& myList, int n,
                             //  ^^
                std::string starter, int leftParens, int rightParens){
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use reference if you want to update the variable in the caller context (in other words, if you want to change the variable in `main`).
2. Whenever a class allocates memory, you probably need to follow the "rule of three" (constructor, copy-constructor, copy-assignment operator). If you don't, you'll get into trouble if you ever make a copy of the original class [like your call to `myFunction` as it currently stands]

Comment: Thanks Mats. I'm not sure I understand your comment though. Are you saying something different than R Sahu above? Even if I had a constructor, copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator, wouldn't I still be in trouble as myFunction is working with a copy of myList?

Comment: To make your code immediately work, you need to use reference to pass the list to `myFunction`. But if you EVER need to make a copy of the list [For example call some function that does some changes the list, but don't want to make the changes to the actual list], you need rule of three.